# Fasteest algorithm to compute avg distance between two Sets of points

Tags: computer-vision, geometry, artificial-intelligence, d, computational-geometry

Please see picture :

[image]

Given the set of points marked in Red, I take two consecutive points (here 0 and 1 - these numbers are  just for illustration , thus not the index in the array holding these points.).

I take their midpoint. From the midpoint I draw a normal on each segments in the Green set (segment = line between two consecutive points).

The blue line is such a normal. The intersection point falls between points 10 and 11. I record the length of it.

The black normal line however, is a normal on the line given by points 12 and 13. But, the intersection does not fall between 12 and 13 . So I reject it.

I want to get the median value of the lengths all such accepted lines, measured from the midpoints of the segments in the red set.

My Brute force algorithm is running at `O(MN)` time.

My questions :

1. Is there a standard algorithm for what I am seeking? That is to say, I do not know if the parameter I am measuring has a common name.
2. What is the fastest method of measuring it.

I would love to do some parallel processing, but I am using D, and I am getting :

```
 "core.thread.threadbase.ThreadError@src/core/thread/threadbase.d(1219): Error creating thread"
```

Thank you.

Comment: You’ll be better off measuring distances between points. It’s much faster, and would not produce a significantly different value, since you take the median of all those distances any way.

Comment: Still O(MN) -> it cant be faster?

Comment: O notation is how running time scales with number of points, it's not how fast it is. If finding the distance between each pair of points is too slow, you can use an R*-tree or similar spatial indexing to speed up finding the nearest point.

Comment: Are you happy if you get the averages of coords of red and green points and use the distance between those two average coords? It may not be exactly what you are currently doing, but a well aproximated value.

Comment: @Ripi2 - no, the average may be twisted if we have large outliers

Comment: How many points are there ? If few, parallelization will perform worse.

Comment: Varies. 
for 50 to 2500

Comment: I think your "black line" example is confusing me, does this sum up your goal properly?:

Calculate the median value of the lengths of all normals calculated from the midpoints of 2 consecutive points on the red set to its intersection with a segment of the green set

If this is the case, I don't understand why the black line would ever come into play - 1) it is a normal from the green set, 2) it isn't calculated from a midpoint.

Would there not be a single length for each set of consecutive points on the red line, which you could then find the median of?